# Spring Security Login and Checking Issue

Tags: spring, gwt, jboss, spring-security

I am using Spring 4 + Spring Security 3.2 + GWT , after deploying the application on Jboss and call it `(http://localhost:8080/login/login.htm)` I get this error  **JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available.**

With Spring 3.1 + spring security 3.1 was workiung fine.

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/gwt/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/*.html" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/ws/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <form-login login-page="/login/login.htm" authentication-failure-url="/login/login.htm?error=true" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="userid,JSESSIONID" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" />
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/login/login.htm?invalid=true" session-fixation-protection="newSession">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" />
    </session-management>
    <custom-filter ref="ajaxTimeoutRedirectFilter" after="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER" />
</http>
```

any help?

Thanks

Comment: The request looks weird (lgin?). Besides, without any config details it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: I updated the info, any additional info? Thanks

Comment: The ordering of your intercept-url patterns is wrong. `/ws/**` will never be reach due to the `/**` above it. `/**/*.html will match your login which will protect the login page. You have 2 `<logout />` elements merge them into one.

Comment: I removed the /ws/** and merged the logout but still the same issue.

Comment: I got this message /j_spring_security_check
description JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available.